# chromecustomtab xamarin android MainActivity has leaked ServiceConnection CustomTabsServiceConnectionImpl@43a61ad that was originally bound here

Tags: xamarin.android, chrome-custom-tabs

I used chromecustomtab in my xamarin android project, i can bind service using CustomTabActivityManger class, but there is no option for unbind the service in that class.

and as i am not unbinding, it always throws me error of memory leak.

I am using Nuget - xamarin.Android.Support.CustomTabs version 26.1.0.1

code is as below

```
namespace Android.Support.CustomTabs
{
  public class CustomTabsActivityManager
  {
    public CustomTabsActivityManager(Activity parentActivity);

    public CustomTabsSession Session { get; }
    public Activity ParentActivity { get; }
    public CustomTabsClient Client { get; }

    public event CustomTabsServiceDisconnectedDelegate CustomTabsServiceDisconnected;
    public event CustomTabsServiceConnectedDelegate CustomTabsServiceConnected;
    public event ExtraCallbackDelegate ExtraCallback;
    public event NavigationEventDelegate NavigationEvent;

    public static CustomTabsActivityManager From(Activity parentActivity, string servicePackageName = null);
    public bool BindService(string servicePackageName = null);
    public void LaunchUrl(string url, CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = null);
    public bool MayLaunchUrl(string url, Bundle extras, List<string> otherLikelyUrls);
    public bool Warmup(long flags = 0);

    public class ExtraCallbackEventArgs
    {
        public ExtraCallbackEventArgs();

        public string CallbackName { get; set; }
        public Bundle Args { get; set; }
    }

    public delegate void NavigationEventDelegate(int navigationEvent, Bundle extras);
    public delegate void ExtraCallbackDelegate(object sender, ExtraCallbackEventArgs e);
    public delegate void CustomTabsServiceConnectedDelegate(ComponentName name, CustomTabsClient client);
    public delegate void CustomTabsServiceDisconnectedDelegate(ComponentName name);
}
```

Comment: Could you please post more detailed codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I can bind service using `CustomTabActivityManger` class, but there is no option for unbind the service in that class

## Analyze：

Usually we could directly use [unbindService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context#unbindService(android.content.ServiceConnection)) to unbind the `Service`. But in the [CustomTabActivityManger](https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidSupportComponents/blob/master/customtabs/source/Additions/CustomTabsActivityManager.cs) source code we could found there no `UnBindService()` method. And you can't get the `CustomTabsServiceConnection` instance from outside so that it's hard to unbind the service in your `Activity`:

```
public class CustomTabsActivityManager
{
    ...
    CustomTabsServiceConnectionImpl connection;
    ...

    public bool BindService (string servicePackageName = null)
    {
        ...

        connection = new CustomTabsServiceConnectionImpl {
            CustomTabsServiceConnectedHandler = (name, client) => {
                Client = client;
                var evt = CustomTabsServiceConnected;
                if (evt != null)
                    evt (name, client);
            },
            OnServiceDisconnectedHandler = (name) => {
                var evt = CustomTabsServiceDisconnected;
                if (evt != null)
                    evt (name);
            }
        };

        return CustomTabsClient.BindCustomTabsService (ParentActivity, servicePackageName, connection);
    }
} 

class CustomTabsServiceConnectionImpl : CustomTabsServiceConnection
{
     ...
}
```

## Solution：

You could create a custom `CustomTabsActivityManager` class and add the `UnBindService()` method:

```
public class MyCustomTabsActivityManager
{
     CustomTabsServiceConnectionImpl connection;

     public Activity ParentActivity { get; private set; }
     public CustomTabsClient Client { get; private set; }

     CustomTabsSession session = null;

     ...

     public void UnBindService()
     {
         if (connection != null)
         {
             ParentActivity.UnbindService(connection);
             Client = null;
             session = null;
          }
     }
}
```

Then, you could use this `UnBindService()` in your `Activity`:

```
protected override void OnDestroy()
{
    myCustomTabsActivityManager.UnBindService();
    base.OnDestroy();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ,but my CustomTabsActivityManager class just have public bool BindService(string servicePackageName = null); to bind the service so i got confused what to pass as connection at the time of UnbindService. i added my code snapped in question.

Comment: @Query, create a your own `MyCustomTabsActivityManager` class which extends from `CustomTabsActivityManager `, then create the `UnbindService()` method and pass the connection parameter.

Comment: @Query, I have wrote it in the Solution part of my answer.

Comment: I tried it but there is some issue with extends, as  i am using visual studio and i am not able to extend class , did you ever try with visual studio with c# ?

Comment: @Query, I have tested it on my side without any issue, what is the "class" you can't extend?

Comment: I tried to exted CustomTabsActivityManager, if you have working demo thn can you please pass it to me